# Laravel HasRelationships.php Error Occured

Tags: laravel, eloquent

One user has one profile. So i need to add record in here. I did , but I got following error

```
 $user = User::find(20);

        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->first_name = $data['firstName'];
        $profile->last_name = $data['lastName'];
        $profile->dob = $data['dob'];
        $profile->gender =  $data['gender'];
        $profile->contact_no =$data['contactNo'];
        $user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Error

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\Project Repo\Interviews\cmg\laravel_member_mis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php on line 745 and exactly 4 expected
```

Comment: Please show us the `profile` relation from `User` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not supposed to create a record like that. Try this:

```php
$profile = Profile::create([
     // Fill your colums here, like so
     // 'user_id' => $userId, ...
);
```

or, after defining `User` -|---|- `Profile` relationship inside your `User` model, you can do it like this too:

```php
$profile = $user->profile()->create([
     // Fill your colums here, like so
     // 'user_id' => $userId, ...
);
```